# How can I use qTip2's hover on the text in a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, qtip2

I'm trying to use qTip2 with the text for a check box on my webpage.

I have this in my site.master:

```
$(".qtip-hover").qtip({
    style: { classes: 'qtip-bootstrap' },
    position: {
        my: "bottom left",
        at: "top left"
       }
})
```

I would like to add a hover element to the "Has Account?" part of this code.

```
<td width="15%"><label class="editCheckHeader" for="acct">Has Account?</label></td>
```